# How to insert text out of xml entries with etree.Element

Tags: python, elementtree

I built an xml file with lxml.etree, and this is the result:

```
<BigData>
  <user>
    <enum>
      <tree>sometext</tree>
    </enum>
   </user>
</BigData>
```

I am trying to put an entry and come up with this:

```
<BigData>
  <user>**this_is_the_extra_text**
    <enum>
      <tree>sometext</tree>
    </enum>
   </user>
</BigData>
```

Any idea on how to do this?
if i use user = SubElement(user, BigData).text = 'this_is_the_extra_text', i get an error.
  Note: i just want plain text there, not a new xml entry.

Thanks!

Comment: The etree module has a "comments" method. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: no i think comment method will add <!--  text --> and i don't want the brackets :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `user` is a variable referencing `<user>` element, you can simply set its `text` property to add text node as the first child.

This is the setup for demo :

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.Element('BigData')
>>> user = ET.SubElement(root, 'user')
>>> enum = ET.SubElement(user, 'enum')
>>> print ET.tostring(root)
<BigData><user><enum /></user></BigData>
```

and the following is the output after setting `user.text` :

```
>>> user.text = 'this_is_the_extra_text'
>>> print ET.tostring(root)
<BigData><user>this_is_the_extra_text<enum /></user></BigData>
```

If you want to add the text node after other child element however (in other words, text node isn't going to be the first child), you'll need to set `tail` property of the preceding element instead. For example, adding text node after `enum` element works as follow :

```
>>> enum.tail = 'this_is_the_extra_text'
>>> print ET.tostring(root)
<BigData><user><enum />this_is_the_extra_text</user></BigData>
```

Comment: Thanks, i was using .text in the end and an error occured, when i apply text in different line it's all fine.
However, while i "pretty_print=True" at the end, i get a one-liner for <user> tag. Any ideas on how to fix that also?

Comment: Printing well formatted XML in python is an old problem that I still don't know of any ultimate ready-to-use solution for. Each of lxml's `pretty_print=True` and minidom's `toprettyprintxml` has its own know issue...

Comment: Maybe worth spending time to write a small library specifically for petty-printing XML

Comment: oh well ok...since it works, let it be. Marked as answered. Thanks ;)

Comment: what if *this_is_the_extra_text* after `<enum/>`